# Inserting value of combobox into a database in WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, combobox

I want to insert a combobox value into a database. My code how I insert:

```
string query = "insert into DonorsDB values ('" + DName.Text + "'," + DAge.Text + ",'" + DGender.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + DPhone.Text + "','" + DBloodGroup.SelectedValue.ToString() + "')";

Con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("Donor successfully saved!");
Con.Close();
```

But when I want to show data into the listview I have something like this:

[image]

What can I do to insert only values from comboboxes?

Comment: Please use parameters to prevent SQLi...

Comment: And schema-qualify your object (table) names and always specify a column list for an insert statement. Learn about the [using statement](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/usage-and-importance-of-using-in-C-Sharp472/).  Develop good habits.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `DGender.SelectedValue.ToString()` and  `DBloodGroup.SelectedValue.ToString()`. The underlying object under SelectedValue is not the `Gender` class\enum that you are expecting. It's of type `ComboBoxItem`, which after calling `ToString` return fully qualified name of the class.

You have to extract you actual `Gender` value from the `SelectedItem` Property and then call the `ToString` method on it (same with the `DBloodGroup.SelectedValue`)